# Where can I find how many Skip Challenge Stars I have?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

I noticed that I have some items that allow me to skip Challenges for characters, but I cannot find how many I actually own, outside of an actual match.  I would like to know where I can find how many I currently own so that I can plan out their use.  I did not find it in the Stickerbook.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, outside of a game there is no way to tell. When you are in a game, however, you can simply press menu button at any time to view/skip challenges by pressing Y(on Xbox versions). The amount of skips you have is also shown.